# How to speed up word extraction from RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a soundcloud search program,
I am extracting search data by using:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/search?q= Anything &client_id= Myid
```

And exported to RichTextBox,
Then I extract the information I want into the ListBox, each type in a different ListBox like:

```
title in ListBox1
username in ListBox2
```

The problem is this code takes a little long time if the research data is large,
The question is can I speed up my code? Or is there a faster way?
This is my code:

```
    Dim si As Integer = -1
Dim test As String = ""
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("""title"":""") Then
        Dim startTITLE As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("""title"":""")

        If test.Contains(""",") Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(test, String.Empty)
            Dim title As String = test.Replace("""title"":""", String.Empty).Replace(""",", String.Empty)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(title)
            test = ""
            si = -1
        Else
            si += 1
            test += RichTextBox1.Text(startTITLE + si)
        End If
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer2.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("""username"":""") Then
        Dim startTITLE As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("""username"":""")

        If test.Contains(""",") Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(test, String.Empty)
            Dim username As String = test.Replace("""username"":""", String.Empty).Replace(""",", String.Empty)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(username)
            test = ""
            si = -1
        Else
            si += 1
            test += RichTextBox1.Text(startTITLE + si)
        End If
    Else
        Timer2.Stop()
        Timer3.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("""artwork_url"":""") Then
        Dim startTITLE As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("""artwork_url"":""")

        If test.Contains(""",") Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(test, String.Empty)
            Dim url As String = test.Replace("""artwork_url"":""", String.Empty).Replace(""",", String.Empty)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(url)
            test = ""
            si = -1
        Else
            si += 1
            test += RichTextBox1.Text(startTITLE + si)
        End If
    Else
        Timer3.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do this clean-up and assign a string to a ListBox when you get the text from the API, not after you have added the text to a RichTextBox. Use that only for presentation, not storage; you can use a List of class objects to store the text parts you download. You don't need those Timers anymore.

Comment: I extracted the information directly for the RichTextBox without downloading the API file, yes I used the RichTextBox for viewing now. I will replace it with String when I finish. I also used it to delete the text that I extracted and search again so that the text does not repeat

Comment: Timers don't tick that fast, by default no faster than 64 times per second, regardless of how small you make the Interval.  So with 3 timers it can't be faster than 47 msec per line, you'll notice that.  Use 1 timer and it will be instantly 3 times faster.  Consider to convert more than one line of text per Tick for another easy improvement.  Consider a BackgroundWorker so the code can run at full speed.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks man it got faster when I put them in a single timer, I don't know why I didn't think about it xD, I'm going to try BackgroundWorker thanks

Comment: It's faster now thanks man
Timer finished in 23 seconds
BackgroundWorker finished in 15 seconds

Comment: You could also think about a full text search like Elasticsearch. There are some .NET tutorials out there about it.